# Switching between TCP and UDP simultaneously

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp

I am working on robot control project where I should primarily (1)send some data about speed and fixed positions to the robot then (2)start a realtime control using my PC and repeat.
I chose to use TCP/IP for the first step and for realtime UDP/IP.
I tried to code this, but I believe something is missing.

I have some problems:

1- When there is no incoming (clients) connections accept function didn't return valid socket nor Message[10] is printed!!

2- Is it ok to Sendto using the same server IP and port?

3- Is this the right way to switch between UDP and TCP back and forth or there are some considerations should be undertaken?

```
while(Comm_Loop)
{
    while (TCP_Loop)
    {   
        TCP_Client = accept(TCP_Server, (struct sockaddr*) &Client_Address, &Client_Address_Length) ;
        if ( TCP_Client != INVALID_SOCKET)
        {                   
            if (Data_Trans) 
            {
                State = send(TCP_Client, Msg, sizeof(Msg), 0) ;
                if (State != SOCKET_ERROR)
                    TCP_Loop = 0 ;
                else 
                    cout << Message[8] ;
            }
        }
        else cout << Message[10] ;
    }
    Check_Send = sendto(UDP_Socket,
                        UDP_Send_Packet,
                        sizeof(UDP_Send_Packet),
                        0,
                        (LPSOCKADDR) &Socket_Address, 
                        sizeof(Socket_Address));

        fd_set  SockSet  ;  
        timeval Time_Out ; 

        FD_ZERO(&SockSet) ;        
        FD_SET(UDP_Socket, &SockSet);  

        Time_Out.tv_sec  = 5;  
        Time_Out.tv_usec = 0 ;  

        State = select(0, &SockSet, (fd_set *)NULL, (fd_set *)NULL, &Time_Out) ;

        if((State > 0) && (FD_ISSET(UDP_Socket, &SockSet) != 0)) 
        { 
            Check_Recieve = recvfrom(UDP_Socket,
                                    UDP_Recieve_Packet,
                                    Buffer_Length,
                                    0,
                                    NULL,
                                    NULL);
            TCP_Loop = 1 ;
        }
        else 
        { 
            // Reception timeout
            Comm_Loop = 0; 
        }
    }

    closesocket(TCP_Client) ;
    closesocket(TCP_Server) ;
    closesocket(UDP_Socket) ;

     WSACleanup() ;

     return 0;
     }
```

Comment: Do you care about packet loss? If yes stick to TCP/IP.  If no use UDP.  If you feel the need to implement UDP pack re-send (in case of loss) then use TCP/IP.  Most of the TCP/IP overhead is in opening the initial connection.  Once open there is very little difference in speed over a reliable connection.

Comment: I will try both techniques, but I thought TCP/IP is non realtime

Comment: Stating that one should use TCP if one "feels the need to implement UDP" is practically unsound advice, IMO -- on today's Internet, for better or worse (mostly for the worse), with overabundance of NAT'ing and firewalls of most bizarre configurations, adding to this that connection termination is left as a condition to be handled by _application_ layer, choosing UDP over TCP has become more and more of a solution. Ideally, TCP is the only protocol we need for most of our use cases, but practically it has all but failed in that regard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1- When there is no incoming (clients) connections accept function
>   didn't return valid socket nor Message[10] is printed!!

Normal behavior by accept() is to block (i.e. not return) until either an incoming TCP connection is received, or an error occurs.  If you don't want accept() to block, you can set the `TCP_Server` socket to be non-blocking, so that instead of blocking it returns -1 and sets errno to EWOULDBLOCK instead.

As far as Message[10] not printing, keep in mind that the stdout/cout stream is *buffered*, which means any text you send to it won't actually show up in the Terminal window until either you've printed a newline character ('\n' or std::endl) or manually flushed the stream.  So if you aren't seeing the output you expected in a timely manner, you might want to verify that your Message[10] string contains a newline character, or alternatively append `<< std::endl;` to the end of your `cout << blah` calls.

> 2- Is it ok to Sendto using the same server IP and port?

That question is ambiguous -- same server IP and port as what?

If you are asking if you can send your UDP sockets to the same IP address and port that were set in the accept() call (i.e. `Client_Address` in your code), you can do that, but it will only work if your robot has set up a UDP socket to bind to that port number in the UDP port-space.  (Note that a UDP socket and a TCP socket can both bind to the same port without interfering with each other since they have different port-spaces, but by the same token you won't ever see TCP-data appear on your UDP socket or vice versa)

> 3- Is this the right way to switch between UDP and TCP back and forth
>   or there are some considerations should be undertaken?

It looks like it could more or less work, although a more robust design would be one that uses non-blocking sockets and always passes all of the sockets (i.e. the original TCP socket that you pass in to accept(), the per-TCP-connection TCP socket(s) that were returned by accept(), and your UDP socket) into every select call's read-fd_set, and then always checks all of those sockets (via FD_ISSET()) after select() returns and reacts appropriately when any of them is ready-for-read.  That way your program could always handle incoming TCP data while simultaneously handling incoming UDP data, rather than switching from a mode where it handles only TCP to a mode where it handles only UDP (and ignoring any data that doesn't correspond to its current mode; because usually ignoring incoming data makes for a bad experience for the client/robot whose requests you are ignoring).  This would also allow you to accept() incoming TCP connections at any time (since an incoming TCP connection would cause your `TCP_Server` socket to select as ready-for-read, at which point you could then call accept() on it again).